# How to take user input for 2d array in a vector data structure in C++ without using two for loops over rows and columns

Tags: c++, stl, vector, multidimensional-array

I was just playing with vectors in C++, and one way to take user input and put in a vector is like this:

```
vector<int> v(5);

cout << "Enter 5 integers: \n";

istream_iterator<int> int_itr(cin);
copy(int_itr, istream_iterator<int>(), v.begin());
```

I want to know if the same is possible for a 2d array:

```
vector < vector<int> > input(3,vector<int>(2,0));
```

One way of doing is iterating over rows and columns `for i=0 to rows.....for j=0 to cols take input`I want to know ways apart from this using vector datastructure to process input for multi-dimensional array

Comment: Your example will produce a buffer overflow with an input containing more than 5 numbers.

Comment: You know that you can treat a 1D array as a 2D array by simply accessing it in the following way `a(i,j) := a[i*cols+j]//pseudo code`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, I think, by doing this:

```
istream_iterator<int> in_iter(cin), eof;
vector<vector<int> > vec(3, vector<int>(in_iter, eof));
// there you create a vector from a pair of iterators, in_iter and eof
```